# Run docker for windows in a VM running on a linux host

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I want to run windows executables in a docker container.

I cannot run windows containers in linux docker:

```
$ docker run --rm microsoft/nanoserver
Unable to find image 'microsoft/nanoserver:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from microsoft/nanoserver
bce2fbc256ea: Pulling fs layer 
b1b0c61be11f: Pulling fs layer 
docker: image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform.
```

I tried running a windows 10 VM and installing docker for windows in there. The installation went fine, but starting docker yields this error:

```
Unable to start: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: 'MobyLinuxVM' failed to start.

Failed to start the virtual machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.

'MobyLinuxVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID E8803091-3163-4906-8547-F3422532D501)

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID E8803091-3163-4906-8547-F3422532D501).
at Start-MobyLinuxVM, <No file>: line 300
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 395
at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:line 36
at Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx, Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean executeAfterStartCleanup) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line 77
at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Start>b__0() in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line 61
at Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:line 59
```

I have verified that hyper-v is in fact enabled.

Is it possible to have a linux host running a windows VM running docker to run windows executables in a container, or am I trying to do something impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Your second problem (‘MobyLinuxVM’ failed to start) can be solved by running this command in powershell, it helped me.
Use 64/32bit powershell as your windows is. Then reboot.

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype Auto
```

souce (https://forums.docker.com/t/mobylinuxvm-failed-to-start/15175/7)